# Jquery Supersized 3.1 captions

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using the jquery Supersized 3.1.3 plugin, which all works well, and I was wondering if it was possible to add html to the images' title attribute/slide captions? The code snippet below includes html in the title - found on a featured site - but I'm not sure how to re-encode it in the slidecaption div as html. Any help greatly appreciated, S.

The code (partial) which defines the image/s:

```
slides  :   [       //Slideshow Images
            {
            image : 'images/temp-image.jpg', 
            title : '&lt;a href=/About/News/International_Innovation.aspx&gt;&lt;h4&gt;Building Bridges for International Innovation&lt;/h4&gt; &lt;p&gt;Does studying art and design translate into creative business practices?  RISD + Morisawa team up to find out. &lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;', 
            url : 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/02/larissa/'
            }
        ]
```

The slide captions are displayed in the following div:

```
<div id="slidecaption"></div>
```

Comment: Have you tried putting it in as straight HTML?

Comment: Doh! Am going to delete this question! Many thanks for your help, s.

Comment: No, don't delete!  Let me add this as an answer! ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work if you use regular HTML in the `title:`.